# mdframed cannot reduce margin

Tags: margins, mdframed

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\mdfdefinestyle{graybox}{
    splittopskip=0,%
    splitbottomskip=0,%
    frametitleaboveskip=0,
    frametitlebelowskip=0,
    skipabove=0,%
    skipbelow=0,%
    leftmargin=0,%
    rightmargin=0,%
    innertopmargin=2mm,%
    innerbottommargin=2mm,%
    roundcorner=2mm,%
    backgroundcolor=gray!20}


\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=graybox]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\columnbreak
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

How do I remove that top margin inside the mdframe?

Already tried this but doesn't work:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=graybox]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vskip -2\baselineskip
\lipsum[1]
\columnbreak
\vskip -2\baselineskip
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to adjust the `\multicolsep` variable:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\mdfdefinestyle{graybox}{
    splittopskip=0,%
    splitbottomskip=0,%
    frametitleaboveskip=0,
    frametitlebelowskip=0,
    skipabove=0,%
    skipbelow=0,%
    leftmargin=0,%
    rightmargin=0,%
    innertopmargin=2mm,%
    innerbottommargin=2mm,%
    roundcorner=2mm,%
    backgroundcolor=gray!20}


\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=graybox]
\setlength{\multicolsep}{2pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\columnbreak
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

From the documentation of `multicol`:

> As its first action, the multicols environment measures the current
>   page to determine whether there is enough room for some portion of
>   multicolumn output. This is controlled by the ⟨dimen⟩ variable
>   `\premulticols` which can be changed by the user with ordinary LATEX
>   commands. If the space is less than `\premulticols`, a new page is
>   started. Otherwise, a \vskip of `\multicolsep` is added.

`\multicolsep` is kicking in as `multicols` is the first thing in the environment.  By default `\multicolsep` is `12pt plus 4pt minus 3pt`, which is the same order of magnitude as the baselineskip/blank line in a standard document.